# My Postfix has gone wild, is it compromised

Tags: postfix, email-server

Today, I found my server couldn't work because it was filled. I checked the logs and they had grown enormously, I deleted them so as things could work. now with current logs I'm seeing a lot of suspicious activity.

Mail log :

```
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16724]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16904]: match_hostaddr: 61.67.184.122 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13321]: input attribute name: nexthop
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12192]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12800]: input attribute value: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17483]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12468]: smtp_get: EOF
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17928]: send attr milter_actions = 17
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16135]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19163]: input attribute value: 7476A1659B3
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14164]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19366]: input attribute value: smtp
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15307]: match_hostname: dsl093-059-178.blt1.dsl.speakeasy.net ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15951]: milter8_connect: milter inet:127.0.0.1:20209 version 2
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15865]: send attr ident = smtp:202.91.239.165
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15569]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key ycliu6000@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12901]: disconnect from dsl093-059-178.blt1.dsl.speakeasy.net[66.93.59.178]
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13166]: match_hostaddr: 202.53.71.60 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18364]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12205]: input attribute value: 2048
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14859]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18082]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz opendkim[19722]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19586]: name_mask: resource
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14764]: match_hostaddr: 122.201.66.80 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12265]: input attribute name: count
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19034]: match_hostaddr: 82.71.212.10 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18460]: match_hostaddr: 190.146.184.219 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17099]: match_hostaddr: 178.83.29.189 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17710]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14232]: disconnect event to all milters
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15782]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18174]: milter_macro_lookup: "v"
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12122]: send attr sender = 
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16633]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15479]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13872]: event: SMFIC_CONNECT; macros: j=veepiz.com {daemon_name}=veepiz.com v=Postfix 2.3.3
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15132]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16806]: E5A4C1654DE: reject: RCPT from unknown[59.163.57.239]: 554 5.7.1 <someone09102004@yahoo.com.tw>: Relay access denied; from=<mjjjr@googlegroups.com> to=<someone09102004@yahoo.com.tw> proto=SMTP helo=<59.163.57.239.static.vsnl.net.in>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14527]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12222]: match_list_match: gmail.com: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15648]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: address
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13525]: match_string: hotmail.com ~? veepiz.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12639]: permit_auth_destination: barbarita98@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18793]: milter8_connect: milter inet:127.0.0.1:20209 version 2
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13076]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17002]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18678]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13243]: milter_macro_lookup: "{rcpt_addr}"
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13626]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18566]: match_hostaddr: 112.166.135.242 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18913]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: queue_id
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16226]: < unknown[61.19.246.53]: RCPT TO: <nico12261@hotmail.com>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12213]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key big_resist99@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13785]: match_list_match: 61.133.8.74: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16360]: < unknown[200.68.18.101]: RCPT TO: <kingntust@msn.com>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14682]: send attr ident = smtp:201.236.80.197
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13712]: input attribute value: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12331]: > unknown[200.6.252.70]: 250 2.0.0 Ok
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17297]: milter8_connect: milter inet:127.0.0.1:20209 version 2
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13946]: report connect to all milters
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12980]: send attr address = leopard100@seed.net.tw
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15223]: send attr address = 26bc2@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16046]: input attribute name: address
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13423]: match_hostaddr: 110.74.129.159 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18264]: match_hostaddr: 200.160.111.154 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12158]: input attribute name: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14952]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15045]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14014]: ctable_locate: install entry key beautiijunkii@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12165]: match_hostaddr: 189.7.37.81 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15390]: < unknown[77.91.195.16]: RSET
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14083]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16450]: match_string: gmail.com ~? veepiz.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/qmgr[12109]: B868E165652: to=<ndsghyoarkvfr@kimo.com>, relay=none, delay=13716, delays=13522/194/0/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mx1.mail.tw.yahoo.com[203.188.197.119] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12150]: permit_mynetworks: ks390655.kimsufi.com 188.165.248.79
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16724]: match_list_match: 208.87.240.34: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16904]: match_list_match: 61-67-184-host122.kbtelecom.net.tw: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12192]: input attribute name: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13321]: input attribute value: gmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12800]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17483]: input attribute name: rate
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12468]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17928]: send attr milter_events = 0
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16135]: reject_unauth_destination: 8654321@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19163]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14164]: input attribute name: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19366]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: nexthop
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15307]: match_hostaddr: 66.93.59.178 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15951]: milter8_connect: events 
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15865]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15569]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[195.239.156.234]: 554 5.7.1 <ycliu6000@yahoo.com.tw>: Relay access denied; from=<ftink@aol.com> to=<ycliu6000@yahoo.com.tw> proto=SMTP helo=<mail.bkrb.ru>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12901]: master_notify: status 1
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13166]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18364]: match_hostaddr: 190.26.210.23 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12205]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14859]: match_list_match: 98.142.210.165: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18082]: permit_mynetworks: unknown 124.95.140.14
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz opendkim[19722]: smfi_opensocket() failed
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12713]: < unknown[190.182.52.113]: RCPT TO: <6n6m@yahoo.com.tw>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19586]: name_mask: software
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14764]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12265]: input attribute value: 1
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19034]: match_list_match: pancake.2280.net: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18460]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17099]: match_hostname: 178-83-29-189.dynamic.hispeed.ch ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17710]: match_hostaddr: 61.155.164.76 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15715]: < unknown[202.91.239.165]: RCPT TO: <a0286260095@yahoo.com.tw>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15782]: rewrite_clnt: local: 216328@yahoo.com.tw -> 216328@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18174]: milter_macro_lookup: result "Postfix 2.3.3"
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12122]: send attr address = darlage917@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16633]: match_hostaddr: 96.9.160.96 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtp[19166]: D8DCA164E37: to=<fj677@gmail.com>, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.67.27]:25, delay=572, delays=342/214/0.11/16, dsn=5.1.1, status=bounced (host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.67.27] said: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the recipient's email address for typos or 550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn more at                              550 5.1.1 http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596 l14si8292456ybg.13 (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14232]: milter8_disc_event: quit milter inet:127.0.0.1:20209
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15479]: input attribute name: flags
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13872]: reply: SMFIR_CONTINUE data 0 bytes
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15132]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `7964@yahoo.com.tw' -> transp=`smtp' host=`yahoo.com.tw' rcpt=`7964@yahoo.com.tw' flags= class=default
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16806]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14527]: match_hostaddr: 189.16.128.130 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12222]: maps_find: virtual_alias_maps: @gmail.com: not found
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15648]: input attribute name: address
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13525]: match_string: hotmail.com ~? localhost.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12639]: ctable_locate: leave existing entry key barbarita98@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18793]: milter8_connect: events 
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13076]: resolve_clnt: `' -> `buttsex101@hotmail.com' -> transp=`relay' host=`hotmail.com' rcpt=`buttsex101@hotmail.com' flags= class=relay
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17002]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18678]: reject_unauth_destination: chamundapharma@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13243]: milter_macro_lookup: result "boysor2005@hotmail.com"
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13626]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18566]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18913]: input attribute name: queue_id
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16226]: extract_addr: input: <nico12261@hotmail.com>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12213]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=0
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13785]: send attr request = disconnect
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16360]: extract_addr: input: <kingntust@msn.com>
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14682]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: status
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13712]: public/cleanup socket: wanted attribute: (list terminator)
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17297]: milter8_connect: events 
Aug 18 23:09:29 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13946]: milter_macro_lookup: "j"
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12980]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15223]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16046]: input attribute value: caroline_louise1982@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13423]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18264]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12158]: input attribute value: 0
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14952]: permit_mynetworks: li371-14.members.linode.com 96.126.122.14
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15045]: > unknown[187.105.132.234]: 250 2.1.5 Ok
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14014]: extract_addr: in: <beautiijunkii@hotmail.com>, result: beautiijunkii@hotmail.com
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12165]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15390]: abort all milters
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14083]: match_list_match: 190.147.205.152: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16450]: match_string: gmail.com ~? localhost.com
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12150]: match_hostname: ks390655.kimsufi.com ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16724]: send attr request = disconnect
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16904]: match_list_match: 61.67.184.122: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/qmgr[12109]: C1E66164A28: to=<gjwgshgdhktfu@kimo.com>, relay=none, delay=79045, delays=78851/194/0/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: host mx1.mail.tw.yahoo.com[203.188.197.119] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12192]: input attribute value: 0
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13321]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: recipient
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12800]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17483]: input attribute value: 1
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12468]: match_hostaddr: 46.181.195.57 ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17928]: send attr milter_non_events = 4294967040
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16135]: permit_auth_destination: 8654321@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19163]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14164]: input attribute value: 4096
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19366]: input attribute name: nexthop
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15307]: match_hostname: dsl093-059-178.blt1.dsl.speakeasy.net ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15951]: milter8_connect: requests SMFIF_ADDHDRS SMFIF_CHGHDRS
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15865]: input attribute name: status
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15569]: generic_checks: name=reject_unauth_destination status=2
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12901]: connection closed
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13166]: match_hostaddr: 202.53.71.60 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18364]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12205]: input attribute name: (end)
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14859]: generic_checks: name=permit_mynetworks status=0
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18082]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 127.0.0.1/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz opendkim[12241]: exited with status 69, restarting
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12331]: < unknown[200.6.252.70]: MAIL FROM: <agmikjkvnqjkay@yahoo.com>
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12713]: extract_addr: input: <6n6m@yahoo.com.tw>
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14764]: match_hostaddr: 122.201.66.80 ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12265]: private/anvil: wanted attribute: rate
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19034]: match_list_match: 82.71.212.10: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18460]: match_list_match: 190.146.184.219: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19723]: dict_eval: const  mail
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17099]: match_hostaddr: 178.83.29.189 ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[17710]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 10.182.130.68/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15715]: extract_addr: input: <a0286260095@yahoo.com.tw>
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15782]: send attr request = resolve
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[18174]: milter8_connect: non-protocol events for protocol version 2: SMFIP_NOUNKNOWN SMFIP_NODATA 0xfffffc00
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12122]: private/rewrite socket: wanted attribute: flags
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16633]: match_hostname: unknown ~? 50.57.111.177/32
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14232]: disconnect from unknown[202.53.71.60]
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15479]: input attribute value: 0
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[13872]: > unknown[123.30.186.36]: 220 veepiz.com ESMTP Postfix
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[19586]: connect from unknown[196.46.27.11]
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15132]: ctable_locate: install entry key 7964@yahoo.com.tw
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[16806]: > unknown[59.163.57.239]: 554 5.7.1 <someone09102004@yahoo.com.tw>: Relay access denied
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[14527]: match_list_match: unknown: no match
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[12222]: mail_addr_find: sun.chengyuan@gmail.com -> (not found)
Aug 18 23:09:30 veepiz postfix/smtpd[15648]: input attribute value: ast187@yahoo.com.tw
```

I also keep getting emails like this :

```
Subject:    Postfix SMTP server: errors from unknown[81.24.210.138]
From:   "Mail Delivery System" <MAILER-DAEMON@veepiz.com>
Date:   Thu, August 18, 2011 1:03 pm
To:     "Postmaster" <postmaster@veepiz.com>
Priority:   Normal
Options:    View Full Header |  View Printable Version  | Download this as a file

Transcript of session follows.

 In:  RSET
 Out: 250 2.0.0 Ok
 In:  MAIL FROM: <yrgwpwmq@googlegroups.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.0 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jjconstant@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <kaissy57@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jsmiles38@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jaikudoiberica@gmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jljcm4321@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jackson.mccarter@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <lahiii@hotmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jheyblacksoul@msn.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <jacquelineduyck@gmail.com>
 Out: 250 2.1.5 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO: <k501319@ms17.hinet.net>
 Out: 554 5.7.1 <k501319@ms17.hinet.net>: Relay access denied
 In:  RSET
 Out: 250 2.0.0 Ok
 In:  MAIL FROM: <dulfhixfgwpvv@gmail.com>
 Out: 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage
 In:  RSET
 Out: 250 2.0.0 Ok
 In:  MAIL FROM: <uuiipcrauy@kimo.com>
 Out: 452 4.3.1 Insufficient system storage
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

I've contacted admins at rackspace but they cannot offer me any help for unmanaged servers. I'm gutted and want to stop this weird activity. Any advice ?

Comment: btw, those emails in log are unrecognisable

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You have an open relay. Change the `mynetworks` variable to `mynetworks = 127.0.0.1`. Reset all passwords (just to make sure).

After that do a SMTP check for your server at http://mxtoolbox.com and look if it is still an open relay.

By the way reduce logging to the standard value. Another tip: paste the logs directly to this question next time, rewrite your question to plain readable(!) English. And accept answers to your former questions.

**Edit**

The logging can be reset to the default by (re)setting

```
debug_peer_level = 2
debug_peer_list =
```

(yes, the last line ends with the equal sign)

**Edit 2**

I forgot to mention the settings in `master.cf` where there maybe lines ending with `smtpd -v` or even more than one `-v`. Remove the `-v`s.

Comment: ive done all you've said but it appears its still acting as an open relay. check last comment

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/302818/how-to-close-an-open-relay-in-postfix the mailqueue keeps growing regardless check http://pastebin.com/Rm6vdaUL

Comment: Thanks for posting the resolution on your contact form, adding RECAPTCHA is always a good idea! Also, I wanted to thank everyone for using our tools, we are always looking for additional tools to add, if you have any ideas please let us know!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log and postmaster email it seems like you're running an open relay - this is problem #1 that needs to be fixed.  Not being a postfix guru I can only point you at [the Postix relating and access control documentation](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html).

Problem #2 is that you're out of disk space on whatever drive is queueing your mail -- You can probably fix this by dumping your postfix queue.  (That I know how to do -- run the command `postsuper -d ALL` as root).

---

You **must** fix the open relay problem -- Open relays are bad for you and for the <s>environment</s> internet.  If your server remains an open relay for any length of time you will be listed on a multitude of spam blocklists.  Check your blacklist status on [mxtoolbox](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) or a similar site once you fix the problems above and take the necessary steps to clean up any mess that may have been made.

Comment: hi guys how do i reduce postfix logging to a minimum

Comment: @SirLojik - Refer to Chapter 1, Verse 9 of the Postfix Documentation ( http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#syslog_howto ) for information on Postfix logging :)

Comment: Guys ive done what mailq said and voretaq7, but every time i run postsuper -d ALL i keep geeting more mail deleted from queue. it seems its still acting as an open relay. when i run postqueue -p i get this http://pastebin.com/P8pvKpP5

Comment: So what is in the logs, after reducing the log level (as posted above)? Create a new question with "How to close an open relay in Postfix?" And please follow the advices given above before. Even the very helpful (first) link of @voretaq7!

Answer (score -2):

I used wireshack to find out script being used for mailing. It turned out to be my contact form. I've used [reCAPTCHA](http://recaptcha.net) to secure it. I would also like to share more knowledge on how I fixed it.

- I did what mailq and voretag7 suggested.
- modified this script I got on the Internet, to block those spamming IPs.
  create `spamblock.sh`, give proper admin permissions and ran it on a `cron` every 10mins

.

```
#!/bin/bash
IPT=/sbin/iptables
LIMIT=10
#cd /root/Filters
# first get one minute of log
grep "`date +"%b %d %H:%M:" --date="1 minutes ago"`" /var/log/maillog > minutelog
# now extract the rejected attempts, sort and count uniq ip
cat minutelog | grep "reject:" | cut -d" " -f10 | cut -d"[" -f2 | cut -d"]" -f 1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sed 's/^[ \t]*//' > tmp1
# for each line in result
while read line
do
MYCOUNT=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`
MYIP=`echo $line | cut -d" " -f2`
if [ $MYCOUNT -lt $LIMIT ] ;
then
echo $MYIP is ok: $MYCOUNT attempts
else
echo blocking the spammer at $MYIP with $MYCOUNT attempts
$IPT -I INPUT -i eth0 --proto tcp -s $MYIP --destination-port 25 -j DROP
echo $MYIP >> blocked.smtp
fi
done < tmp1
rm -f minutelog
rm -f tmp1
```

- Created a script to periodically execute this command. to clear queues

.

```
postfix flush
postsuper -d ALL deferred
```

Before I found out what script it was, I recommend doing the above. Thanx for your help guys.

Comment: I have to **explicitly** warn everybody to do what Sir Lojik recommends as workaround! Cleaning the queues in production leads to **mail loss**! Dropping connections based on mail server rejects leads to a **self-made** DoS!

Comment: I can **encourage** everybody to get rid of the real problem by removing malicious scripts.