# How to close an open relay in Postfix?

Tags: linux, centos, postfix

I've discovered my server has been an open relay. I asked about it and tried all the answers in [My Postfix has gone wild, is it compromised](https://serverfault.com/questions/302776/my-postfix-has-gone-wild-am-i-hacked) but still its acting up. Every time I run `#postsuper -d ALL` I get thousands of emails being deleted.

Output of `#postqueue -p`

```
                                             chadhapayal@hotmail.com

    76F99164161     6273 Fri Aug 19 00:59:30  MAILER-DAEMON
    (host d.mx.mail.yahoo.com[209.191.88.254] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
                                             fvbmpfkdbps@yahoo.com

    7A99B1640ED     2181 Fri Aug 19 00:58:59  psqzmku@yahoo-inc.com
    (host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.37.88] said: 421 RP-001 (COL0-MC2-F4) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
                                             chcarley@msn.com
                                             cheetah1@msn.com

    7FAF7164140     1304 Fri Aug 19 00:59:25  aogxhka@kimo.com
    (host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F33) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
                                             benjaminundelke@msn.com
                                             birdboy@msn.com
                                             bozoburnet88@msn.com
                                             bratsue@msn.com
                                             browns@msn.com
    (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72] while sending RCPT TO)
                                             a1cleanteam@hotmail.com
                                             asif_capricoralosth002@hotmail.com
                                             atif_sh2000@hotmail.com
                                             atsut@hotmail.com
                                             avihs2000@hotmail.com
                                             baeza212@hotmail.com
                                             bajen@hotmail.com
                                             barby_nicotra@hotmail.com
                                             beautiful_paty@hotmail.com
                                             bee_bee26@hotmail.com
                                             bigone_2@hotmail.com
                                             biswasg1@hotmail.com
                                             bl0ndie219@hotmail.com
                                             bontobee@hotmail.com
                                             brendanchong@hotmail.com
                                             brendo22@hotmail.com
                                             bruhjordano@hotmail.com
                                             cain_joshua16@hotmail.com
                                             calhatfield@hotmail.com
                                             camv@hotmail.com
                                             carla_saldes@hotmail.com

    7C5BF1640DE     2021 Fri Aug 19 00:58:55  yeycwdpibpvh@yahoo.com.tw
    (host mx1.mail.tw.yahoo.com[203.188.197.119] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
                                             pengcw@kimo.com
    (host h.mx.mail.yahoo.com[66.94.236.34] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
                                             roger.weng@yahoo.com
    (host mx4.hotmail.com[65.55.37.120] said: 421 RP-001 (COL0-MC4-F3) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
                                             p714560@hotmail.com
                                             pc662@hotmail.com
                                             vanessa6773@hotmail.com

    7BCB31641CA     2000 Fri Aug 19 00:59:46  mwpneeiaw@ms37.hinet.net
    (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72] while sending RCPT TO)
                                             chachid-mas@hotmail.com
                                             chaoz_devilz@hotmail.com
                                             chriswwjd@hotmail.com
                                             clementine619@hotmail.com
                                             coolkawen@hotmail.com
                                             cottoncandy0511@hotmail.com
                                             cowboy_x87@hotmail.com
                                             crusada@hotmail.com
                                             ctjgao@hotmail.com
                                             cuet_cuet@hotmail.com
                                             cumiks@hotmail.com
                                             dailiklaw@hotmail.com
                                             dale_pippin@hotmail.com
                                             dazacu@hotmail.com
                                             deid449@hotmail.com
    (host mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.94] said: 421 RP-001 (BAY0-MC2-F9) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
                                             cheif99@msn.com
                                             chobee3@msn.com
                                             connorhennemann@msn.com
                                             cozmonster@msn.com

    751AF16418F     1823 Fri Aug 19 00:59:33  bxyscezusjqztb@yahoogroups.com
    (delivery temporarily suspended: lost connection with mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.37.72] while sending RCPT TO)
                                             c_rosaria_c@hotmail.com
                                             cecily611@hotmail.com
                                             cesarcaicedo@hotmail.com
                                             coeur_perce@hotmail.com
                                             cq133783@hotmail.com
                                             ctonshaw@hotmail.com
                                             dam3a_81@hotmail.com
                                             dannyk333@hotmail.com
                                             daysi1977@hotmail.com
                                             dddd_00@hotmail.com
    [root@veepiz ~]# postsuper -d ALL
    postsuper: Deleted: 386 messages
    [root@veepiz ~]# postsuper -d ALL
    postsuper: Deleted: 2 messages
    [root@veepiz ~]#

here is the last 200 entries in mail log

    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28080]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28080]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28081]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28081]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[19570]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28081]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28082]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28082]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28082]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[6273]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[19570]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28083]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28084]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[28332]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[220.227.90.238]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29849]: 478C31642C2: reject: RCPT from unknown[46.191.138.61]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28083]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[25922]: AD8671642EA: reject: RCPT from unknown[195.239.156.234]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[6799]: 69DB816427F: to=, relay=g.mx.mail.yahoo.com[98.137.54.238]:25, delay=51, delays=50/0.01/0.55/0, dsn=4.7.0, status=deferred (host g.mx.mail.yahoo.com[98.137.54.238] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 [TS01] Messages from 50.57.111.177 temporarily deferred due to user complaints - 4.16.55.1; see http://postmaster.yahoo.com/421-ts01.html)
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28084]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28083]: smfi_opensocket() failed

    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: host mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F29) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[27099]: 229DD1642DB: reject: RCPT from unknown[218.2.81.49]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[6273]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28091]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[30005]: 9703B1642E0: reject: RCPT from li371-14.members.linode.com[96.126.122.14]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: lost connection with mx1.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] while sending RCPT TO
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[2802]: 69DB816427F: to=, relay=alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[74.125.113.27]:25, delay=51, delays=50/0/0.41/0.24, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK 1313705613 ck9si6068954vdc.130)
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28092]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[28266]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[200.11.138.106]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29703]: 58A181642AD: reject: RCPT from unknown[91.212.182.135]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29969]: disconnect from unknown[190.110.86.206]
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29580]: 784071642DC: reject: RCPT from unknown[187.2.153.162]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[28444]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[200.11.138.106]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29995]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from LAubervilliers-151-11-6-238.w193-251.abo.wanadoo.fr[193.251.53.238]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28091]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29648]: 31044164282: reject: RCPT from unknown[189.208.110.210]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31818]: 64D901642DD: host mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.126] said: 421 RP-001 (BAY0-MC4-F44) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command)
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[27350]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from li371-14.members.linode.com[96.126.122.14]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28092]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[19570]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31818]: 64D901642DD: lost connection with mx3.hotmail.com[65.54.188.126] while sending RCPT TO
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28092]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28093]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use

    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[28818]: DCE801642D2: reject: RCPT from unknown[201.90.70.99]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=

    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[25126]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[208.87.240.34]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28111]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[6273]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29057]: 54C2C1642CC: reject: RCPT from unknown[208.87.240.34]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/cleanup[29438]: 940B01642E5: message-id=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[19570]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28117]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[28988]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from ns353096.ovh.net[91.121.90.130]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[1533]: 940B01642E5: proxy.ezaya.fr [94.23.180.150] not internal
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28117]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[1533]: 940B01642E5: not authenticated
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28117]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28118]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28118]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28118]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[6273]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[26516]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[201.236.80.197]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28120]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to bind to port inet:20209@localhost: Address already in use
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28120]: OpenDKIM Filter: Unable to create listening socket on conn inet:20209@localhost
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31828]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.34/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.184] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC4-F26) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[6273]: exited with status 69, restarting
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz opendkim[28120]: smfi_opensocket() failed
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[29969]: connect from unknown[121.129.73.163]
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtp[31818]: 64D901642DD: to=, relay=mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136]:25, delay=14, delays=14/0.02/0.39/0.04, dsn=4.0.0, status=deferred (host mx2.hotmail.com[65.55.92.136] said: 421 RP-001 (SNT0-MC1-F22) Unfortunately, some messages from 50.57.111.177 weren't sent. Please try again. We have limits for how many messages can be sent per hour and per day. You can also refer to http://mail.live.com/mail/troubleshooting.aspx#errors. (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
    Aug 19 01:13:11 veepiz postfix/smtpd[26719]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[221.235.190.176]: 554 5.7.1 : Relay access denied; from= to= proto=SMTP helo=
```

`main.cf`

```
    # Global Postfix configuration file. This file lists only a subset

    command_directory = /usr/sbin

    daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

    #myhostname = mail.veepiz.com
    #myhostname = virtual.domain.tld


    #myorigin = $myhostname
    myorigin = veepiz.com


    mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, $mydomain
    #mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
    #mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain,
    #   mail.$mydomain, www.$mydomain, ftp.$mydomain

    #mynetworks_style = class
    #mynetworks_style = subnet
    mynetworks_style = host

    mynetworks =127.0.0.1
    #mynetworks = $config_directory/mynetworks
    #mynetworks = hash:/etc/postfix/network_table

    #relay_domains = veepiz.com

    #relayhost = $mydomain
    #relayhost = [gateway.my.domain]
    #relayhost = [mailserver.isp.tld]
    #relayhost = uucphost
    #relayhost = [an.ip.add.ress]

    #alias_maps = dbm:/etc/aliases
    alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
    #alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, nis:mail.aliases
    #alias_maps = netinfo:/aliases

    #alias_database = dbm:/etc/aliases
    #alias_database = dbm:/etc/mail/aliases
    alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
    #alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/opt/majordomo/aliases

    home_mailbox = Maildir/

    #mail_spool_directory = /var/mail
    #mail_spool_directory = /var/spool/mail

    #mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail
    #mailbox_command = /some/where/procmail -a "$EXTENSION"

    #mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:/var/lib/imap/socket/lmtp

    #luser_relay = $user@other.host
    #luser_relay = $local@other.host
    #luser_relay = admin+$local


    #
    #header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks


    #local_destination_concurrency_limit = 2
    #default_destination_concurrency_limit = 20

    #debug_peer_level = 2

    debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5


    sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix


    newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

    mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

    setgid_group = postdrop

    html_directory = no

    manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
    irectory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples

    # readme_directory: The location of the Postfix README files.
    #
    readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
    smtpd_milters           = inet:127.0.0.1:20209
    non_smtpd_milters       = inet:127.0.0.1:20209
    milter_protocol         = 2
    milter_default_action   = accept
    smtpd_timeout = 30000s
    smtpd_recipient_limit = 10000
    default_destination_recipient_limit = 50000
    initial_destination_concurrency = 50
    default_destination_concurrency_limit = 200
    max_use = 2000
    hopcount_limit = 5000
    minimal_backoff_time = 100s
    smtpd_hard_error_limit = 2000
```

`/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
    #

    smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd 


    pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
    cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
    qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
    #qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
    tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
    rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
    bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
    verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
    flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
    proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
    smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
    # When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
    relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
    #       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
    showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
    error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
    discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
    local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
    virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
    lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
    anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
    scache    unix  -   -   n   -   1   scache

    maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}

    old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}

    cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}

    uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)

    ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
    bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
      flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
```

Comment: Please fix your formatting and filter your logs to only include marginally useful information.

Comment: These logs and config files look clean (now). All attempts from "outside" get refused. The mails in the queue are probably "recovering" from the deferred queue while the system _was_ an open relay. Keep removing mails from the queue.

Comment: Oh yes. And fix the DKIM "crap".

Comment: [root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 2627 messages
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 202 messages
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 1 message
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 2 messages
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 460 messages

Comment: tried this and still there is mail in queue oot@veepiz log]# postfix flush
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL
postsuper: Deleted: 172 messages
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL deferred
postsuper: Deleted: 5 messages
[root@veepiz log]# postsuper -d ALL deferred
postsuper: Deleted: 49 mess

Comment: @mailq looks like the queue is getting refilled every after i delete

Answer (score 3):

I just ran an open relay test from http://www.abuse.net/relay.html and your server passed all the 17 relay tests? May be a local user himself is using your server for abuse.

-$

Comment: possible - or there's really that volume of "legit" mail...

Comment: found a solution here http://serverfault.com/questions/302776/my-postfix-has-gone-wild-am-i-hacked